# Issue in accessing UNC path from MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Hi I have deployed my MVC 5 application on IIS on Production server by configuring it with other ID on IIS.

UCN path trying to access as follows,
\ servername\folder1\folder2\tryingToAccessFolder

My application is using UNC path from the code.
While running localy, it runs fine, But after deploying application on IIS, and accessing it from other machine, it shows "Access Denied Error..".

Help to resolve this issue.

My application is using UNC path from the code.
While running localy, it runs fine, But after deploying application on IIS, and accessing it from other machine, it shows "Access Denied Error..".

Help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Show code sample please, really hard to help you with out it.

Comment: You access it on server side or it's link on View?

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your application on IIS, your application will be run in an Application Pool (for more information about Application Pool, you can check  the following link
http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2245511/IIS-and-ASPNET-The-Application-Pool.htm
By default, Application Pools operate under the Network Service user account, which has low-level user rights. In your case, I think the account that your Application Pool is using (or the identity of the application pool) doesn't have enough permission to access your UNC folder.

You can configure your application pool to run under one of the built-in user accounts in the Windows. To specific the an identity for an Application Pool, you could check the following link.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx

Note: You must make sure the account that specific to be identity for an Application Pool have enough permission to access your UNC folder.

Comment: We have already provided enough access permissions to the configured ID. But still getting "Access Denied error". Is there any changes we need to do in IIS settings ?

Comment: Have you restarted application pool after update its identity? You must provide both permission for Sharing and Security of UNC folder. If the problem still persit, please provide the code that cause problem, I will try to figure out.